# React re render after each step of bubble sort algo

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, bubble-sort

Ok, so I would like to rerender the bar I am displaying after each step of bubble sort. But so far my function only re-renders after all are sorted. Can someone please advise on the correct way to handle this problem?

```
  function bubbleSort(array: number[]) {
    var i;
    var j;
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      // Last i elements are already in place
      for (j = 0; j < array.length - i - 1; j++) {
        // Checking if the item at present iteration
        // is greater than the next iteration

        if (array[j] > array[j + 1]) {
          // If the condition is true then swap them
          var temp = array[j];
          array[j] = array[j + 1];
          array[j + 1] = temp;
        }
        alert(array);
        setTimeout(() => {
          forceUpdate();
        }, 2000);
      }
    }
  }
```

[image]
[image]

```html
import { IonButton, IonInput } from '@ionic/react';
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import './Sort.css';

interface ContainerProps {
  name: string;
}

//try force updatae
function useForceUpdate() {
  let [value, setState] = useState(true);
  return () => setState(!value);
}

const Sort: React.FC<ContainerProps> = ({ name }) => {
  //demo force uppdatge
  let forceUpdate = useForceUpdate();

  // param for the number of elements taht will be in the array
  const [numberOfElements, setNumberOfElements] = useState(5);

  //   repeat value so that no style changes when main value is changes
  const [numberOfElementsStyleInput, setNumberOfElementsStyleInput] =
    useState(numberOfElements);

  //   param for the array itself
  const [arrayOfElements, setArrayOfElements] = useState<number[]>([]);

  //ref to outer block for divention retrivals
  const outerUnit = useRef() as React.MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement>;

  //ref for dynamic scalling of outer-unit by getting container size params
  const containerRef = useRef() as React.MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement>;

  //const to hold max after each new array gen
  const [max, setMax] = useState<number>(0);

  let myRefs: any = useRef([]);

  // test useState for div dimentions
  const [_heigth, set_heigth] = useState(0);

  // generate array oif random number in range of block size and of count user input
  const generateArrayOfnumbers = (numOfElements: number): number[] => {
    let tempArray: number[] = [];

    for (let index = 0; index < numOfElements; index++) {
      let num: number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 47 + 3);
      tempArray[index] = num;
    }

    return tempArray;
  };

  //get max value of array for scale neededs
  function getMax(array: number[]) {
    return array.reduce((a, b) => {
      return Math.max(a, b);
    });
  }

  function wait(ms: any) {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    var end = start;
    while (end < start + ms) {
      end = new Date().getTime();
    }
  }

  //n^2
  // Creating the bblSort function
  function bubbleSort(array: number[]) {
    var i;
    var j;
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      // Last i elements are already in place
      for (j = 0; j < array.length - i - 1; j++) {
        // Checking if the item at present iteration
        // is greater than the next iteration

        if (array[j] > array[j + 1]) {
          // If the condition is true then swap them
          var temp = array[j];
          array[j] = array[j + 1];
          array[j + 1] = temp;
        }
        alert(array);
        setTimeout(() => {
          forceUpdate();
        }, 2000);
      }
    }
  }
  //Main return
  return (
    <div className="container" ref={containerRef}>
      <strong>{name}</strong>

      <div
        id="outer-unit"
        className="outer-unit-class"
        ref={outerUnit}
        style={
          window.innerHeight > 1024
            ? {
                height: window.innerHeight * 0.6 + 'px',
                width: window.innerWidth * 0.6 + 'px',
                position: 'relative',
              }
            : {
                height: window.innerHeight * 0.4 + 'px',
                width: window.innerWidth * 0.65 + 'px',
                position: 'relative',
              }
        }
      >
        {/* {arrayOfElementsHeights.map((current_h, index) => {
          let temp_array_H: number[] = [];

          return setArrayOfElementsHeights();
        })} */}
        {arrayOfElements.map((currentElement, index) => {
          return (
            <div
              ref={(ele: any) => (myRefs.current[index] = ele)}
              key={index}
              id={'inner-unit-' + index}
              className="inner-unit-class"
              block-value={arrayOfElements[index]}
              style={{
                position: 'absolute',
                left:
                  (outerUnit.current.clientWidth / numberOfElementsStyleInput) *
                    index +
                  'px',
                bottom: '0',
                marginLeft: outerUnit.current.clientWidth * 0.006,
                marginRight: outerUnit.current.clientWidth * 0.0015,
                height:
                  outerUnit.current && max
                    ? ((outerUnit.current.clientHeight -
                        outerUnit.current.clientHeight * 0.1) /
                        max) *
                        arrayOfElements[index] +
                      _heigth +
                      'px'
                    : '',
                width: outerUnit.current
                  ? outerUnit.current.clientWidth / numberOfElementsStyleInput -
                    (outerUnit.current.clientWidth / 100) * 1.5 +
                    'px'
                  : '',
                backgroundColor: '#db7420',
              }}
            >
              <h3>{arrayOfElements[index]}</h3>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
      <IonInput
        type="number"
        value={numberOfElements}
        placeholder="Enter Number"
        className="input-num"
        onIonChange={(e) => setNumberOfElements(parseInt(e.detail.value!, 10))}
      ></IonInput>
      <IonButton
        onClick={() => {
          const data = generateArrayOfnumbers(numberOfElements);
          setArrayOfElements(data);
          setMax(0);
          setMax(getMax(data));
          setNumberOfElementsStyleInput(numberOfElements);
        }}
      >
        Random generate
      </IonButton>
      <IonButton
        onClick={() => {
          bubbleSort(arrayOfElements);
        }}
      >
        Bubble Sort
      </IonButton>
      <section className="info-section">
        <h1>Bubble Sort algorithm using JavaScript</h1>
        <p>
          Bubble sort algorithm is an algorithm that sorts the array by
          comparing two adjacent elements and swaps them if they are not in the
          intended order. Here order can be anything like increasing order or
          decreasing order.
        </p>
        <h2>How Bubble-sort works</h2>
        <p>
          We have an unsorted array arr = [ 1, 4, 2, 5, -2, 3 ] the task is to
          sort the array using bubble sort. Bubble sort compares the element
          from index 0 and if the 0th index is less than 1st index then the
          values get swapped and if the 0th index is less than the 1st index
          then nothing happens. then, the 1st index compares to the 2nd index
          then the 2nd index compares to the 3rd, and so on…
        </p>
      </section>
      <br />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Sort;
```

UPDATE:

```
  async function bubbleSort(array: any) {
    let isSorted = false;
    while (!isSorted) {
      isSorted = true;
      for (let i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
        if (array[i] > array[i + 1]) {
          [array[i], array[i + 1]] = [array[i + 1], array[i]];
          isSorted = false;

          setTimeout(() => {
            setArrayOfElements(array.slice());
          }, 2000);
        }
      }
    }
    return array;
  }

bubbleSort(arrayOfElements.slice());
```

Comment: Can you paste more of the component here? It's not possible to tell how you are managing state in the component, and that determines how your component re-renders.

Comment: Use clearTimout after array have sorted

Comment: sure I will update with the whole file

Comment: here is a repo with all the code base:
https://github.com/Alex-Kamenev/Algo-Viz

Comment: clearTimout did not help with the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, in general, React component will rerender when either input Props change, or hooks change. You are sorting your array in place mutating the arrayOfElements along the way. Your component will render the correct state as soon as you use `setArrayOfElements`.

Quickly looking at your example I'd say there are two steps to fixing your issue.

1. Avoid directly mutating the state array by creating a copy of input array, for example using slice api

```
onClick={() => {
  bubbleSort(arrayOfElements.slice());
}}
```

2. Update your state in bubble sort function

```
 ...
 alert(array);
 setArrayOfElements(array.slice();
 ...
```

Note that updating the state will override your initial array, which might not be what you want. I'd suggest you create two state variables in that case, one to hold the unsorted array, and the other one to hold the current state.

Force update is just a hack, which is not a correct solution to re-rendering issues in React, so you can remove it.

Also, you need to make your buble sort async and probably add meaningful timeouts between iterations. You won't see any gradual state changes if function is not async, as the next state will be rendered after the bubble sort function has finished.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This was helpful but the problem still persists. The array is displayed as generated and then displayed sorted but none of the steps are displayed.

Comment: What should I do to make the timeouts meaningful?

Comment: By meaningful I just meant, you need to set the timeout time to your liking. However, your current usage is incorrect. Since your bubble sort function is async now, you need to first set your state, then `await` for cetain amount of seconds. I won't write that function for you. Create a Promise which will resolve after N seconds and `await` for it.

Comment: Andrej Jurkin Thank you! Largely with help from your answer and comments I got it to work and have posted the working version of the code as answered below. I see now the error I was making in the use of setTimeout.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is the solution I ended up with:

```
  // encapsulate setTimeout in a promise, so we can await it below
  const wait = (timeout: any) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(resolve, timeout);
    });
  };

  //n^2
  // Creating the bblSort function
  async function bubbleSort(array: any) {
    let isSorted = false;
    while (!isSorted) {
      isSorted = true;
      for (let i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
        if (array[i] > array[i + 1]) {
          [array[i], array[i + 1]] = [array[i + 1], array[i]];
          isSorted = false;

          setArrayOfElements(array.slice());
          await wait(1000);
        }
      }
    }
    return array;
  }

<IonButton
        onClick={() => {
          bubbleSort(arrayOfElements.slice());
        }}
      >
```